# Can we use an arbitrary programming language to dynamize HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, web

I've only ever used **javascript** on HTML pages (dom manipulation, AJAX calls, you know what I mean) and I **suspect** this is also true for most web developers.

However, do we **need** to use javascript ? I think I remeber seeing VBScript used in that way as well. So that's two possible languages to be used for scripting HTML.

But what should I do in order to be able to use **any scripting language** to do what we normally do with javascript?

Comment: use javascript. nobody uses vbscipt

Comment: As long as the browser can execute the code embedded in the page, you can use it. JavaScript is really the only language that can be used like this.

Comment: But still, I see no reason to downvote this question. Explain yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be more specific regarding what you actually want.

If you mean "self-hosted in the browser", then whatever you're writing in either needs to be:

- Supported natively by the browser (e.g., JavaScript, and not much else that's cross-browser), or
- Self-hosted in JavaScript (e.g., [Clamato](http://clamato.net/), a self-hosted Smalltalk dialect)

If you don't mean "self-hosted" then anything that can be transformed to JavaScript, like:

- [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/)
- [ClojureScript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript#readme)

To answer your last question: either write plugins for, or modify, all browsers to support whatever language it is you want (good luck), or write a self-hosted language transformer.

Comment: clojure script? I like the idea of using LISP like stuff .. but is it practical?

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida What do you mean by "practical"?

Comment: Hmm not sure... It's just that it would seem to me so nice to be able to use Lisp (Clojure actually) as scripting language for web pages but then again I suspect there must be a *very* good reason why it isn't.

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida Because most people don't like Lisp? What makes you think there's a *good* reason for why one language wins out over another? It's not like JavaScript is a beloved language; language wars aren't generally won because of technical merit.

Comment: OK you're right of course. Still, thanks for mentioning clojure.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/). There's also Google [Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/), but apparently it's only supported by Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

And there is [Amber](https://github.com/NicolasPetton/amber), another Smalltalk implementation on top of js, both client and server.